# MVC3 Data Context Best Practice

Tags: database, asp.net-mvc-3, controller, repository, datacontext

This is an action I have in my controller.  Is it considered bad practice to be creating and disposing a database connection (i.e. PhotoGalleryContext - which is a connection to a MySql database) inside of this controller as opposed to having an abstraction by having this action done in a data access layer in a model .cs class?

```
    // GET: /Admin/GetPhoto/id
    public ActionResult GetPhoto(int id)
    {
        PhotoGalleryContext db = new PhotoGalleryContext();

        Models.PhotoGallery.Photo photo = new Models.PhotoGallery.Photo();
        photo = db.Photos.Where(p => p.PhotoId == id).Single();

        string filePath = photo.FileLocation;

        db.Dispose();    

        byte[] byteArray;
        try
        {
            byteArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
            return File(byteArray, "image/jpg");
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            //throw;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Where are you disposing of db (PhotoGalleryContext)? It's not in this example?

Comment: Copy paste error, *editted* to show dispose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agree with David, in that it depends on the size of your application.

However, i would suggest to use **dependency injection** to manage the connection for you.

Using something like [StructureMap](http://structuremap.net/structuremap/), you could have something like this:

```
For<PhotoGalleryContext>()
   .HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped
   .Use<PhotoGalleryContext>();
```

Which translates to:

> When something asks for a **PhotoGalleryContext**, give it a new **PhotoGalleryContext** that is **HTTP-scoped** (created at start of request, disposed at end).

That way, StructureMap will automatically open/close the connection for you.

Then your controller can look like this:

```
private readonly PhotoGalleryContext _db;
public AdminController(PhotoGalleryContext db)
{
   _db = db;
}
```

And in your action methods, `_db` will be ready to go for you.

Few lines of code to save a lot of repetitive using statements across your application.

Comment: If I return a model which is still using a shallow copy of the database context will that prevent dispose from being called?

Comment: @TravisJ - no, because rendering of the View is still part of the current HTTP request, *however*, it's bad practice. Your View shouldn't know/care about any DB connection. Why would the model use a shallow copy of the ctx?

Comment: When creating an object to return and copying parts of a db object a shallow copy is kept in the context.  I make hard copies to ensure that when the db object is disposed the data is still in my copy, however I was not sure if not being automatically garbage collected would make this solution hold onto the connection.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid having to use large amounts of overhead, although the code may be more readable, it seems StructureMap would add to the total request time.  HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped is non trivial.

Comment: @TravisJ - your nit picking now i think. I can't see how StructureMap would add too much overhead to the request time. Yes, a using would be less connection time. But if your worried about performance, you should be focusing on core areas such as database queries, HTTP requests, etc. Premature optimization is death. I still don't get why you need to make a shallow copy. You should be mapping your database objects to ViewModels, which are presented to the View. Then you don't have to worry about keeping the data in your original object.

Answer (score 2):

You would probably consider the size of your application when deciding this. I would say separating the model is a best practice, but for smaller apps, maybe you should just wrap the `PhotoGalleryContext` in a using block:

```
using(PhotoGalleryContext db = new PhotoGalleryContext())
{

    Models.PhotoGallery.Photo photo = new Models.PhotoGallery.Photo();
    photo = db.Photos.Where(p => p.PhotoId == id).Single();

    string filePath = photo.FileLocation;
    byte[] byteArray;
    try
    {
        byteArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
        return File(byteArray, "image/jpg");
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        //throw;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: If I were to separate this into the model, would I still just be instantiating the PhotoGalleryManager class every time inside of a controller like this one and then disposing of it at the end?  If my Manager contains many different operations then would it be slow to load the whole manager class for something lightweight like this?

Comment: Is using() better than calling .dispose()?

Comment: using() calls Dispose() at the end brace, an imo makes the code a little more readable at a glance (as long as you nest format your code).